# Problem calling Java from PHP script

Tags: java, php

I am working on windows. I am running PHP (5.1.3) scripts on Tomcat using PHP/Java bridge. Here is my simple code

```
//test.php
<?php
require_once("java\Java.inc");
$systemInfo = new Java("Test");
print $systemInfo->foo();
?>

//test.java
class Test
{
 public void foo()
 {
  System.out.println("hello php");
 }
}
```

Test.class is in the same folder as test.php. But the php file is not able to locate the test class and I get the following error -

```
Fatal error: Uncaught [[o:Exception]:"java.lang.Exception: CreateInstance failed: new Test.
```

If I use a standard class like below. It works -

```
<?php
require_once("java\Java.inc");
$systemInfo = new Java("java.lang.System");
print "Total seconds since January 1, 1970: 
".$systemInfo->currentTimeMillis();
?>
```

What should I do?

1)Should I copy my class to the standard location where all Java classes are kept. (What is this location?)

2) Do some changes in the php.ini file

Comment: Packaging error? Can you post Test.java, or at least it's package and signatures?

Answer (score 1):

have you set the following attribute in php.ini?

```
[java]
java.class.path="/path/to/folder/containing/Test"
```

Also, use a package (like com.jack.Test) when creating classes. It is just convention, but you'll find that it makes a lot of sense once you're creating entire projects

Comment: I changed the php.ini like you said...I am still getting the same error